# Invalid absolute path error when parameterising Excel path on SharePoint site in Power Query

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery, dataformat

I have a valid, working, absolute path to an Excel file on a SharePoint site (e.g. "https://.../Filename.xlsx"), denoted by **"FilePath"**.

I try to import some information from **"FilePath"** via Power Query. Using

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("FilePath"), null, true),
```

works fine. However, if I try to parameterise **"FilePath"** by placing it in the first row of an Excel table named **Source_Files** in column **Source file** found in the same Excel file where my Power Query resides (which I imported to PowerQuery), I always get

```
DataFormat.Error: The supplied file path must be a valid absolute path.
Details:
    FilePath
```

error, whether I try parameterising this way:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Source_Files[Source file]{0}), null, true),
```

or this way:

```
let    
    FilePath = File.Contents(Source_Files[Source file]{0}),
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(FilePath), null, true),
```

How can I parameterise an Excel file on a SharePoint site in Power Query?

Comment: Are there some special characters somewhere? Also, have you tried the SharePoint connector of Power Query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the syntax to replace "FilePath" would be:

`Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Source_Files"]}[Content]{0}[Source file])`

Comment: Thank you @MikeHoney, it works! Now I wonder why... is it because `File.Contents` returns a binary? `File.Contents` works perfectly for tables with UNC path of local or network files, but not with SharePoint links (and I guess files in web adresses). Even with `Text.From` wrapped, `File.Contents` does not work in my case.

Comment: For a  sharepoint, using the sharepoint or onedrive connector is the easiest way. Otherwise you could use `Web.Contents` with the sharepoint API.